# Change texture color or apply color hint in ThreeJS and NPM

Tags: npm, three.js, textures, tint

I need to load a texture and apply it to a plane then be able to change the tint color of the texture. Basically, I would have a color selector. The color is applied to each black pixel of the texture. I tried to use [Jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp) like this:

```
jimp.read(fileName).then(function (image) {
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 6, 4 );

    var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( fileName );
    texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping; 
    texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    texture.offset.set( 0, 0 );
    texture.repeat.set( 1, 1 );

    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map : texture } );
    material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
    material.map.needsUpdate = true;

    var plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    plane.rotation.x = -60 * ( Math.PI/180 );

    scene.add( plane );

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

but I don't know if ThreeJS or Jimp allows this and I could mix them somehow to achieve it. Don't find anything

Comment: You can use `new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture, color: 0x00FF00});` to multiply a texture by a color, but black pixels will stay black... is that something you can work with, or are the input images out of your control?

Comment: If you don't want to use a custom shader, you can always manipulate the image on a canvas, then use that canvas on the material

Comment: Try `material.emissive = new THREE.Color(0x964B00)`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a canvas texture so you can access dynamically to the image...

```
var canvas  = document.createElement( 'canvas' )
canvas.width    = 512 // custom 
canvas.height   = 512 
var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas)
var context = canvas.getContext( '2d' )
```

Now in context you can write or read as normal HTML5 canvas https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_canvas.asp

remember that you have to set

```
texture.needsUpdate = true;
```

the texture when you need to update the texture after context changed

I never used jimp, but if you can output a normal HTML javascript Image object you can copy it into canvas and use it

```
context.drawImage(image,width,height);
texture.needsUpdate = true;
```